# Edit/write workbook without saving under different name

Tags: apache-poi

Is it possible to save a workbook and save it without copying the edited file over the base file?

Here is my code:

```java
File file = new File("base.xlsx");
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);

Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("data");
...
//creating rows and cells, writing stuff
...

//saving
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("edited.xlsx");
workbook.write(fos);
workbook.close();
fos.close();
//now both the base.xlsx and edited.xlsx contain all the new and previous data - and are exactly the same size

//using only
workbook.close();
//the workbook file size changes (approximately to the same as edited.xlsx) and the timestamp is current
//BUT the data doesn't get saved
```

The only other possibility I know of is using an InputStream (but then I get out of memory (10MB .xlsx file and 2GB Heap space))

The confusing part is: why does the base.xlsx file get edited if I write it out to another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of July 2016 (Apache POI 3.15 beta 2), this is not yet supported

In POI, we call this *In-Place Write*. As of fairly recently, both the underlying file-format modules (POIFS and OPC) now support this. (They didn't for a long time, which is why POI has grown up working as it does for saving). However, none of the format-specific modules have been updated to take advantage of this. So, all documents opened at the UserModel level (eg `Workbook` or `HWPFDocument` of `XLSFSlideShow`) currently only support writing out to a new stream

If you're interested in this, the bugs to watch are [#57919](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57919) and [#59287](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59287).

If these matter to you and you want to put some coding time in to help, take a look at the [contribution guide](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html) then join [the dev list](http://poi.apache.org/mailinglists.html) and people can give you pointers!

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!